# How to change(sense) the Orientation of Xamarin forms based on orientation of mobile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created one Xamarin cross-platform app in which it will open the camera only for recording, but the camera should open only in landscape mode, even if the user is keeping their phone in portrait mode, one pop message should come as please open the app in landscape view.

I am not able to sense the orientation of Mobile that either it is in Landscape mode or portrait mode. When I am running my app, it is always taking the width and height of mobile in portrait mode but not based on orientation.

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height) {
if (height > width) {
    IsPotrait = true;
}
else if (width > height) //Landscape mode
{
    IsPotrait = false;
}
base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
}

 protected async override void OnAppearing() {

if (IsPotrait) {
    DisplayAlert("Error", "Please hold up your phone for Landscape 
                         view.", "OK");
    return;
}
else {
    OpenCamera();
}

}

 public void OpenCamera() {
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported) {
    DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
    return;
}

var file = CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions {
    Name = "video.mp4",
    Directory = "DefaultVideos"
});

if (file == null) return;

DisplayAlert("Video Recorded", "Location", "OK");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Xamarin Essentials this works:

```
        DisplayOrientation orientation = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation;
        if(orientation == Xamarin.Essentials.DisplayOrientation.Landscape)
        {
            outerStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal;
        }
        else
        {
            outerStack.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
        }
```

I have it placed in OnAppearing(). So it redisplays the page on the correct format when the device is rotated. OnAppearing() is fired when the device is rotated.

I used this example for the xaml, which displays in two columns, either stacked on above the other or side by side depending upon 'outerStack.Orientation'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

In Splash screen  check the device orientation using height and width.Use the code below

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (height > width ) //It means portrait mode
        {
            //Show popup here
        }
    else if(width > height)//Landscape mode
        {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For xamarin.android you can add `ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape` in MainActivity.cs file to force a orientation for a app.

```
[Activity(Label = "App", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
          LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
          NoHistory = true,
          ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Locale |
                                 ConfigChanges.LayoutDirection,
          ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
```

For iOS you will have to configure it in the info.plist file

[image]

For more details, you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows)

Answer (score 0):

There are already answers above but I do not think they are descriptive enough

In my knowledge `Xamarin.Forms` does not have a clean way for doing this, What I would suggest you do is on the page that you need to check orientation do the following:

Add a boolean property that checks whether or not the device is in portrait mode, also by default set it to true:

```
private bool  _isPotrait= true
public bool IsPotrait 
{ 
  get
 {
   return _isPotrait;
 } 
set
 { 
   _isPotrait=value; 
   OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPotrait));
 }
}
```

See to it that your ContentPage also inherits from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the above to work check this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Now Override the OnSizeAllocated method:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
   base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height); //must be called
}
```

Note that the OnSizeAllocated method may be called many times when a device is rotated.

Now if `height > width` of the device then it means the device is in portrait mode.

So you add the following in your OnSizeAllocated method:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{  
if (height > width ) 
    {
        IsPotrait =true;
    }
else if(width > height)//Landscape mode
    {
        IsPotrait =false;
    }
  base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
 }
```

Once you are done with all this before calling your Camera API all you have to do is check :

```
if(IsPotrait) {//Yes} else {//No}
```

### UPDATE

It's better to Add the [Xamarin.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) Nuget package:

Once you have it add the following using Statement in your MainPage

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;
```

Then get the display metrics using the following API:

```
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
```

And then Get the Orientation using the following where below are the possible out comes:

```
// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189914/discussion-on-answer-by-g-hakim-how-to-changesense-the-orientation-of-xamarin).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this now is with the `Xamarin.Essentials` nuget package. You can use the Device Display Information: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

```
// Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
   var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
   var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;
```

You can get the width and height with this plugin:

```
// Width (in pixels)
var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

// Height (in pixels)
var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
```